# Delete all but first instance in data frame when the rows aren't duplicates in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and it looks something like the first df below. Theres duplicates in col1 but not col2. I want to remove all of the duplicate rows except the first row so that it looks like the second df below.

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| x | 2 |
| x | 3 |
| y | 1 |
| y | 2 |
| y | 3 |

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| y | 1 |

I tried this but it didn't work:

`df %>% group_by(col1) %>% filter(duplicated(col1) | n()!=1)`

Answer (score -1):

We need just `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df, col1, .keep_all = TRUE)
  col1 col2
1    x    1
2    y    1
```

---

Or if we want to use `duplicated`, negate (`!`) and return the first row

```
df %>%
    filter(!duplicated(col1))
  col1 col2
1    x    1
2    y    1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y"), col2 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```